# How can I build a voltmeter / logger?

Tags: design, bluetooth, voltage-measurement

I want to build a device whose primary function is a voltmeter without a display. Instead of having a display I want it to interface with a smart phone via bluetooth to read the voltage. Optionally I would like to be able to press a button on the phone and shut off the circuit for a couple of seconds and turn it back on, all while still sending the readings to the phone.

I need millivolt resolution with a range of ±5V

How could I go about doing this?

I'm a programmer that's pretty new to EE, so please dumb it down if you think I won't understand. Thanks!

Comment: It believe you will get a better answer if you add some more specifics. What is the application? What is the range of voltages you expect to be measuring? What technologies have you considered so far. That type of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any of those specifics and with your statement that you are pretty new to EE you might want to start by taking a look at [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/). There are a lot of examples, modules, and a great support community our there in the Arduino world and it is great for people learning the EE side of things.